# can't use lambda as IComparer

Tags: c#, .net

I always use lambda as IComparer for Array.Sort like this

```
        int[][] array = new int[2][];
        array[0]=new int[2]{1,2};
        array[1]=new int[2]{2,3};
        Array.Sort(array,(a,b)=>a[1]-b[1]);
```

but when I try to use it for SortedSet it does not compile and I am getting

"Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IComparer<int[]>' because it is not a delegate type"

```
        var set = new SortedSet<int[]>((a,b)=>a[1]-b[1]);
```

The only difference is SortedSet is pointing to `System.Collections.Generic` instead of
`System.Collections`

Comment: Code review comment.  You don't need `new int[2]{1,2}`, simply `new int[]{1,2}` (or even `new []{1,2}`); the compiler will count the items for you.  And, if you want to go crazy, you could reduce the whole array initialization to `var array = new []{new[]{11, 12}, new[]{21, 22}};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Comparer.Create<T>`:

```
var set = new SortedSet<int[]>(Comparer<int[]>.Create((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]));
```

`Array.Sort` has [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Sort__1___0___System_Comparison___0__) which accepts [`Comparison<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1?view=netcore-3.1) delegate (`delegate int Comparison<in T>(T x, T y)`), which your lambda is converted to, while `SortedSet` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_SortedSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__) needs [`IComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1).